# What fastboot erase actually does?

Tags: factory-reset, fastboot, motorola-moto-g2

It's been said that we can do a **factory reset** with the following commands:

```
fastboot erase modemst1 
fastboot erase modemst2 
fastboot erase cache
fastboot erase userdata
```

Now, the fastboot CLI provides the following description for `erase`:

> Erase a flash partition.

What does the `erase` command actually do? Does it *erase the partition*, or does do a *factory reset*?

Comment: From what I can find, they just wipe the partition. Great For clean Wipes ahead of a ROM install, not so great when you was trying to delete your personal storage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- This thread on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/general/guide-fastboot-flashing-factory-t3187750) has a post

> ....what is the aim of the "fastboot erase modemst" command?

Answer

> modemst1 and modemst2 are storage partitions for Radio Firmware .... - and it's obviously a recommended practice to wipe these partitions when flashing a newer Radio Firmware

- This [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2277112) thread is all about fastboot commands

`fastboot erase system`

`fastboot erase data`

`fastboot erase cache`

Are explained as

> fastboot allows for about the cleanest of wipes by the way. And each partition can be done separately too.

Elsewhere in same thread

> ... with a lot of new phones `userdata = /data + /sdcard (/data/media)`, so all data, any personally saved files, and system are flushed out permanently with fastboot's erasure. Note that TWRP factory reset would leave `/data/media` intact

So, putting your list of commands in question, a device is being wiped *cleanly* of all the partitions mentioned including *all* data, and thus getting ready to flash a new ROM on the cleanest manner as against *dirty* flash which has remnants of earlier ROM  affecting performance

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for pointing out the thread. Just one question, clearing all these partitions will automatically trigger a recovery process that will bring the device back to default state it comes from factory?

Comment: It would not trigger automatically a recovery process IMO, since you would need to reboot using other means. That is my understanding, as I haven't used these commands for the purpose explained

Comment: I understand, then if after these commands I do a fastboot reboot, when rebooting the system will restore itself or I must do fastboot recovery and trigger the recovery process manually? Thanks for the aid again!

Comment: I think the former, should suffice. Thanks for accepting