# Differences between fastboot erase and fastboot format

Tags: adb, stock-android, fastboot, baseband

I have an asus zenfone 2 laser with radio problem:it doesn't take the line.I want to format modem partition to see if the problem could be solved.I jave a doubt:what is the difference between fastboot erase and fastboot format?What command have I use before flash the modem?

Comment: Related [What fastboot erase actually does?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161103/131553)

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer regarding `Format` and `Erase`. 
Format :
Fastboot will create allocate new block / create file system to the target partition. Not all partition support format feature. System, userdata, cache, boot, recovery.

Erase : 
Fastboot will wipe out the entire partition target. All partition support this erase feature as long as permitted by bootloader.

Both command will "destroy" partition content. You will need any compatible firmware to fix it.

About that modem case :

fastboot erase modem < modem was the partition name.

fastboot flash modem "modem-file*.*"