# Does the fastboot erase cache command wipe all your data off your phone?

Tags: fastboot

As the title says. As i was trying to flash a new recovery to my phone, i followed a tutorial and that said i needed to do this command but now the OS isnt booting up anymore. 
Did this command wipe all the data?

I'm using the phone: Oneplus 5t and used this tutorial

https://www.techrrival.com/flash-recovery-adb-fastboot/

Comment: Our [fastboot tag-wiki](/tags/fastboot/info) is a good starting point for such questions. `fastboot erase cache` should just have erased the cache partition (check the output from that command). But I can't tell how your OS would deal with an unformatted cache partition. If you can still boot into recovery, that should give you a "wipe cache" option. Try that. If it doesn't help. please [edit] your question and include details on which device it is, which ROM you've flashed, what tutorial you refer to, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What fastboot erase actually does?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161103/what-fastboot-erase-actually-does)